# Magento backend listview pricerules

Tags: magento

I have 300+ shopping cart price rules. I need to solve a problem that has to do with continue following rules . I would like in the overview in the backend add the column " stop rules Further processing". Where/how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite the method

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Grid::_prepareColumns()
```

In your new method you need to add something like this:

```
        $this->addColumn('stop_rules_processing', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Stop Rule'),
        'align'     => 'left',
        'width'     => '150px',
        'index'     => 'stop_rules_processing',
    ));
```

Don't forget, that magento strongly do not recommend to edit core files.